# Characters replaced with HTML entities reappear

Tags: php, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

I am having trouble doing a simple `str_replace`.
I am trying to remove all comma's from a string, which does work. But when I try to alter the string again, the commas reappear somehow. I refactored my code to ensure I didn't cause this.

Anyways here is my code. Can anybody spot a bug?

```
 $delim=remDelim(fgets($fo));
#       echo 'before : '.htmlspecialchars($delim);
    $delime =str_replace(",","&#44;",$delim);
    echo 'after : '.htmlspecialchars($delime);
    $delimed = str_replace("<","",$delime);
    echo $delimed.'<br />';

 example output: 
   Jose, jr to Jose&#44; jr  to  Jose, jr
```

Its like my string is being unconverted somehow. I would say that it was most likely I got the names mixed up and used the first string to craft the last. But alas I can see that is not the case.

Comment: At least once I guess everybody gets tricked by this one :).

Comment: His answer is good. The only difference is that with the last `echo` you don't use `htmlspecialchars()`. What gets printed is `&#44;`, but it is HTML, so it is displayed as a comma. Check the HTML source in your browser. [Or check this demo of your code.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gY45Dr)

Comment: It wasn't working on a 12mb page (possibly firefox bug or apache/php as it isn't good with handling large pages, causes freeze aka non-responding and took up to 2GB of ram just loading this page). I viewed source &#44; wasn't there. Then I tried with a 12 kb page. This finally showed the &#44; in source. That was weirdest behavior I have seen from a computer before. And this makes sense why it was always working for the ppl that answered (using a one line input =< 1kb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're viewing this in a browser, note that the browser **WILL** render the character entities as the actual character, not the entity text. Either force the browser into plain-text mode (`header('Content-type: text/plain');`), or view the page's source (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> in firefox)

Comment: tried it on the command line and don't have the problem. so I am sure as well as Marc, that the browser renders it!

Comment: @yoyoma: given you've got 3 variables with VERY similar names, are you sure you're outputting the correct one? Is the above code a direct cut&paste of your script, or a re-typing?